# Changing dynamically background CSS in Meteor-Angular app

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, meteor, meteoric

I'm developing an AngularJS Ionic Meteor app, and I need to change the background color of the botton box of an ionic card depending of it contents (a float). The ranges are:

```
data<=80
81 < data <= 160
161 < data <= 233
234 < data<= 317
318 < data <= 400.
```

Is there a CSS way to do it, or an AngularJS way instead?

Comment: So you are basically saying: between 81 and 160, use a certain background-color; between 161 and 233, use a different bg color; and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). Just setup your CSS background-color properties and set in your controller the appropriate class, for example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if ($scope.data <= 80) $scope.rangeColor = "red";
    // Add more conditional statements
    else $scope.rangeColor = "blue";
  }
}
```

```css
.card {
  border-style: solid;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h4>Data:</h4>
    <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <input type="text" name="data" ng-model="data" required>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <br />
    <div ng-class="rangeColor" class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping text.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You could also implement the conditional statements in your HTML elements:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

}
```

```css
.card {
  border-style: solid;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h4>Data:</h4>
    <input type="text" name="data" ng-model="data" required>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div ng-class="{'red': data <= 80, 'blue': data > 80}" class="card">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        This is a basic Card which contains an item that has wrapping text.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
 ng-style
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

or

```
ng-class
```